# Linq-to-SQL: How to perform a count on a sub-select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm still trying to get my head round how to use LINQ-to-SQL correctly, rather than just writing my own sprocs.

In the code belong a userId is passed into the method, then LINQ uses this to get all rows from the **GroupTable** tables matching the **userId**. The primary key of the **GroupUser** table is **GroupUserId**, which is a foreign key in the **Group** table.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return summary details about the groups a user belongs to
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Group> GroupsForUser(int userId)
    {
        DataAccess.KINv2DataContext db = new DataAccess.KINv2DataContext();
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

        groups = (from g in db.Groups
                  join gu in db.GroupUsers on g.GroupId equals gu.GroupId
                  where g.Active == true && gu.UserId == userId
                  select new Group
                  {
                      Name = g.Name,
                      CreatedOn = g.CreatedOn
                  }).ToList<Group>();


        return groups;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I'd also like to return the total number of Users who are in a group and also the total number of Contacts that fall under ownership of the group.

**Pseudo code ahoy!**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return summary details about the groups a user belongs to
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Group> GroupsForUser(int userId)
    {
        DataAccess.KINv2DataContext db = new DataAccess.KINv2DataContext();
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

        groups = (from g in db.Groups
                  join gu in db.GroupUsers on g.GroupId equals gu.GroupId
                  where g.Active == true && gu.UserId == userId
                  select new Group
                  {
                      Name = g.Name,
                      CreatedOn = g.CreatedOn,
                      // ### This is the SQL I would write to get the data I want ###
                      MemberCount = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GroupUser AS GU WHERE GU.GroupId = g.GroupId ),
                      ContactCount = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contact AS C WHERE C.OwnerGroupId = g.GroupId )
                     // ### End of extra code ###
                  }).ToList<Group>();


        return groups;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the LINQ version of what I wrote in SQL there does the trick, I didn't think it would work!

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return summary details about the groups a user belongs to
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Group> GroupsForUser(int userId)
    {
        DataAccess.KINv2DataContext db = new DataAccess.KINv2DataContext();
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

        groups = (from g in db.Groups
                  join gu in db.GroupUsers on g.GroupId equals gu.GroupId
                  where g.Active == true && gu.UserId == userId
                  select new Group
                  {
                      GroupId = g.GroupId,
                      Name = g.Name,
                      CreatedOn = g.CreatedOn,
                      ContactCount = (from c in db.Contacts where c.OwnerGroupId == g.GroupId select c).Count(),
                      MemberCount = (from guu in db.GroupUsers where guu.GroupId == g.GroupId 
                                     join u in db.Users on guu.UserId equals u.UserId
                                     where u.Active == true 
                                     select gu ).Count()
                  }).ToList<Group>();

        return groups;
    }
```